# Dynamic Breadcrumbs in CodeIgniter According To Web Service Data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make breadcrumbs dynamically from web service data.
I want to show the hierarchy like this: `Beranda / Kugi / Category / Sub-category` where the `Category` is the parent of `Sub-category`

The problem is I get the value of `Sub-category` from `$this->input->GET('KodeSubKategori')` from my tree view. But, I cannot get the value of `Category`.

Here is my controller:

```
//to get the value of Sub-category
$paramSubKategori = $this->input->GET('KodeSubKategori');

    $get_url_subkategori = $this->ws_url->GetUrl('SubKategoriRetrieve?KodeSubKategori='.$paramSubKategori);
    $get_json_subkategori = json_decode(file_get_contents($get_url_subkategori), true);
```

I want to get the data `Category` although I don't click it in tree view

So how can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with GET

```
$this->input->GET('')
```

It is use as

```
$this->input->get('');
```

Read [Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your controller method

```
$data['crumb']=array(
    array('label'=>'Beranda','link'=>'your dynamic link'),
    array('label'=>'Kugi','link'=>'your dynamic link'),
    array('label'=>'Category','link'=>'your dynamic link'),
    array('label'=>'Sub-category','link'=>'') # Last link should be blank for active link
);

$this->load->view('yourfilename',$data); # yourfilename - name of your view file
```

On view **yourfilename.php** page add this-

```
<ul>
    <?php $tb=count($crumb); for($c=0;$c<count($crumb);$c++){ if(($tb-$c)>1){?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $crumb[$c]['link']?>"> <?php echo ucfirst($crumb[$c]['label']);?></a> /</li>
    <?php }else{ ?>

        <li class="active"><?php echo ucfirst($crumb[$c]['label']);?></li>

    <?php } }?>


</ul>
```